# java input and output syntax (Simple)

Tags: java, syntax

I have this import statement:

```
import java.util.List
```

Input:

```
public class solution{ List<String> words (String text, List<String> bannedWords) {//BodyOfMethod } }
```

expected Output: list of strings

My code:

```
HashSet<String> bannedWords = new HashSet<>();
HashMap<String, Integer> validWordsCount = new HashMap<>();

List<Character> result = List<>();
```

It says error can't find symbol for the lines above. My syntax is wrong (I think it's out dated, from an old tutorial). Can I write it as Map instead of HashMap?

Can someone please tell me the correct syntax for the the variable to the input and output?

Comment: `new List<>()` isn't valid. `List` is an interface, not a class. You could use `List<Character> result = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @khelwood thank you. Can I use 'HashMap' or should I make it a 'Map'

Comment: `Map<String, Integer> validWordsCount = new HashMap<>();` is the usual formation.

Comment: Do I need to import a library for that? I'm still learning it and I just read I might need that @khelwood

Comment: Yes, you need to `import java.util.*;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HashSet<String> bannedWords = new HashSet<>();
HashMap<String, Integer> validWordsCount = new HashMap<>();

List<Character> result = List<>();
```

Typically you would type the variables as the interface types (`Set`, `Map`, `List`), and instantiate them with a particular implementation class (`HashSet`, `HashMap`, `ArrayList`). See [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/3890632)

So this would be:

```
Set<String> bannedWords = new HashSet<>();
Map<String, Integer> validWordsCount = new HashMap<>();

List<Character> result = ArrayList<>();
```

All of these types can be imported from `java.util`, e.g.

```
import java.util.*;
```

Comment: Do I need to import a library for that? I'm still learning it and I just read I might need that @khelwood 'import java.util.ArrayList' it wasn't imported